# I have this error in my VB project, what can i do?

Tags: vb.net

> Error 1 Error creating Win32 resources: Error reading icon 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VSProjectApplication.ico' -- The data is invalid.

Comment: Try to [replace it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RGHKDg5Jpg_iBHyBWF_2kL1qkWXiSDDo/view?usp=sharing) (make a backup, of course :).

Answer (score 0):

**2 things to try:**

1. Close the solution and delete the `.suo` file; Visual Studio will recreate it the next time you save the solution or exit Visual Studio.
2. Right Click the project and Unload it. Once it is loaded again right click the project file to edit; it will open up vbproj file which is actually xml. Search for the `ApplicationIcon` tag and remove whatever is inside, or search for the missing file name and delete it.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fd2b06ad-0a5f-471e-9213-3e79df1fd082/error-1-error-creating-win32-resources?forum=vssetup)